Old horror short series 80-90s
I'm really frustrated because I can't remember the names of the series I saw as a kid. 
Not super scary but little.
One episode is in a plane and one man can se a monster on the wing, but nobody will listen - he shoots a hole in the window and when they land the planes wing is broken and scratches. And the man goes away in a ambulance. And sees the monster thing. The end. (I think the man is a well known actor now. But can't remember who)
And one other episode wich I really wanna see again. 
A boy haves the control over his parent. He have the power to send them in the television. And have a sister. He wants cheeseburger all the time. And there are visitors.

There is the TV series The Twilight Zone but from 1959-1964 in black-and-white.
Nightmare at 20,000 Feet (1963) with William Shatner (opens exit window to shoot gremlin)
It’s a Good Life (1961) with Cloris Leachman as mom
(boy makes people disappear to a cornfield)
Your date and descriptions match more with Twilight Zone: The Movie (1983) by Steven Spielberg and John Landis which has remakes of those episodes.
The first description matches both of the "20,000 Feet" episodes but in the 1983 with John Lithgow he shoots the window and scratches are seen on plane.
The second matches more with the 1983 version also of "Good Life" where his parents do whatever he wants because they are scared of him including letting him eat lots of food like hamburgers and he has two sister; he made one sister's mouth disappear and he sent the second sister into the tv to be eaten by a cartoon dragon. Although his family probably were people he picked up like the teacher who visits and helps all of them.
